# Is MDX Query ok or we require changes and how to get data for mdxquery?

Tags: schema, cube, olap-cube

I am new in MDXQuery and Cubes. So I create a cube looks like:

```
<Schema name="Products">
  <Cube name="Products" visible="true" cache="true" enabled="true">
    <Table name="products">
    </Table>
    <Dimension type="StandardDimension" visible="true" foreignKey="name" name="name">
      <Hierarchy name="New Hierarchy 0" visible="true" hasAll="true">
        <Table name="products">
        </Table>
        <Level name="name" visible="true" table="products" column="name" uniqueMembers="false">
        </Level>
      </Hierarchy>
    </Dimension>
    <Measure name="id" column="product_id" aggregator="count" visible="true">
    </Measure>
  </Cube>
</Schema>
```

And no error displayed into Schema workbench. Its connected successfullY, now i want to execute this cube using MDXQuery and wrote below mentioned query.

```
select {
    [Measures].[id]
} ON COLUMNS,

{
  [name]
} ON ROWS

from  Products
```

and click on 'execute' button.

Output looks like:

```
Axis #0:
{}
Axis #1:
{[Measures].[id]}
Axis #2:
{[name.New Hierarchy 0].[All name.New Hierarchy 0s]}
Row #0: 3
```

So, Is this ok or what happened why not query return some value output. Snapshot looks like:
[image: MDXQuery and its output]

Please suggest me.

Thanks,
sawai